# Delphi using pointers to methods properly

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

If I have a Pointer focused to a `FormActivate(Sender: TObject);` -
`MyPtr := @FormActivate;` - how do I run FormActivate with a sender of my choice.
I do not understand how to add in the sender.

Comment: How do you run it without a sender?

Comment: This question is unclear. *Sender* is the form that is being activated. You don't select it; it's automatic. The form holds a pointer to the event already, so you don't need one. What exactly are you trying to do, and what specific problem are you trying to solve? Why do you think you need a *pointer focused to a FormActivate* in the first place? Seems like more of an XY problem than a real question. What problem are you trying to solve where you think getting a pointer to an event handler is needed?

Answer (score -1):

You should not use a Pointer in this case. I don't think that you can even do it as you need the form instance as well as the method. The FormActivate is a plugged into the OnActivate event handler, defined as TNotifyEvent:

TNotifyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;

NB: The "of object" which the compiler interprets to require an instance (the mechnanism hidden from us as it should be).

The correct was to do what you want (not sure that you should be doing it, but hey..) is to replace your Pointer with a MyForm :TMyForm (what ever yours is) and then call:
MyForm.FormActivate(mySender);

Alternatively, you can replace Pointer with a MyEvent :TNotifyEvent, thus:
MyEvent := MyForm.OnActivate;
then call
MyEvent(mySender);

Replacing mySender with whatever you wish in both examples.

I hope that this clears things up for you.

Comment: The procedure does not necessary need to be a procedure for the form (may be bad example). Its that I have a procedure that is located by a pointer and details like "sender" I need control to put into the procedure as Its run. Steve are you saying I have to treat the pointer as an event?

Comment: Steve I have a pointer how do I turn that into an event?.. MyEvent(MyPtr^)(MySender)?

Comment: Ken White I know its automatic but I'm not writing standard code the procedures may be in a *.DLL and many other places.

Comment: @user2522301 When addressing a previous poster add the `@` immediately before the addressees name. **Add details to your question by editing the question** (see the "edit" button under the tags of your question). Do not make up false scenarios, instead present a **real** problem. Now, review your question, change it by editing or delete it if you can't make it sensible. Based on the question and the comments, it seems to be a mess.

Comment: @user What you have isn't a pointer. It's two pointers. One to an instance, on to the method. Of course you used @ and so lost the instance. You can't have this thing be in a DLL, not if it is going to use the Sender argument. In short, you are far out of your depth. Why not let us help you. Tell us about your problem rather than your (non) solution.

Comment: David Heffernan - www.chami.com/tips/delphi/011097D.html Shows calling a procedure with out header data. No one shows adding header data that must be placed on the stack I guess.